# Why are relative image paths resolving as absolute paths?

Tags: html, relative-path

I've read a few resources including [this one](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#relative-urls) about how relative paths are resolved in web browsers. But even after my research I'm still confused because I'm seeing an example of a relative image URL that contradicts everything I've read so far.

I have a webpage with a similar URL to this one: https://www.example.com/uri1/uri2/

There's an image tag on that page with a relative path:

```
<img src="example.png"/>
```

The browser is resolving the image to: https://www.example.com/example.png

This is the correct location of the image. I'm wondering why the browser didn't attempt to resolve the image from: https://www.example.com/uri1/example.png

From what I understand, the latter is where the image should have resolved to.
I looked at the page in both Chrome and FireFox which had identical results.

I'm writing a script that parses through CMS content and resolves relative image paths to fully-qualified ones before downloading the images.

In my case, this isn't working because in the browser, the relative path is actually being resolved to the base of the domain. And so, when my script attempts to resolve the fully qualified image path (e.g example.com/uri1/example.png) it produces the incorrect URL.

Comment: it depends where the html file is located. with 
img src ="example.png", this acts from the base of the folder where the html doc that you are currently accessing. if this fails, either your image is in a different directory, and or your code needs to be correct. 
if you tell your html doc that the image source is example.png, and not ./uri1/uri2/example.png, your browser doesnt know to look in the other folder for it.just like if you told me that you live three doors down the road, I may travel  in either direction 3 doors and if you are not there, then you need correct the direction given

Comment: Thanks for you response @aaronlilly this page isn't listed in a literal directory but listed under an artificial uri structure in ModX. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is there a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in your page?

Comment: @AuxTaco There is! This seems to have been the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AuxTaco I realized that there was a `<base>` tag present on the page. The `<base>` tag is used to overwrite the default resolution of relative paths.

I had to update my script to incorporate the possibility of a `<base>` tag being present on any given page.